# How to properly copy a list in python

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I would like to keep track of bubble sorting algorithm's intermediate states at each iteration. I've tried to cache them in dictionary while loop is running, but i keep getting the same state all the time

Here is my code:

```py
def bubblesort(lst):
    cache = {}
    # Swap the elements to arrange in order
    iter = 0
    for iter_num in range(len(lst)-1,0,-1):
        new_lst = lst
        for idx in range(iter_num):
            iter += 1
            if new_lst[idx]>new_lst[idx+1]:
                new_lst[idx], new_lst[idx+1] = new_lst[idx+1], new_lst[idx]
            cache[f'iter{iter}'] = new_lst
    return cache
```

Here is the output:

```
{'iter1': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter2': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter3': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter4': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter5': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter6': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter7': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter8': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter9': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
 'iter10': [50, 119, 194, 365, 608, 788, 851, 879, 960],
...}
```

As you can see, it outputs sorted list each time. What am I missing here?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that with the line
`cache[f'iter{iter}'] = new_lst`
both the object in the cache dictionary as well as the new_list variable point to the same object.
In the next interation then
`new_lst = lst`
overwrites it with a new object and now the cache, lst and new_list point to the same object.
What you need to do, is to create a 'real' copy of the object. For that you can use the `copy` package.
You should also read about the difference between `shallow and deep copy` as they are very fundamental and the source of a multitude of problems if not understood correctly.

```
from copy import copy
[...]
cache[f'iter{iter}'] = copy(new_lst)
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that, silly mistake that i didn't see :)